# How to pass job number in GNU Parallel?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I pass the variables from a script to the main script in a parallel command like

```
./script1 | parallel -u --jobs 3 "./script2 {}"
```

How can I pass the job number as the second argument of `./script2`?

something like

```
./script1 | parallel -u --jobs 3 "./script2 {} {}" ::: {1..3}
```

but the first `{}` should come from `./script1`.

Note that I do not want the combination of arguments. Instead, the running jobs should be

```
./script2 var1 1
./script2 var2 2
./script2 var3 3
./script2 var4 1
./script2 var5 2
./script2 var6 3
./script2 var7 1
```

Imagine `./script2' writes to files`file1.txt`,`files2.txt`, and`file3.txt`where the number is`{1..3}` or the job number.

I want to make sure only one script is writing to its corresponding file. In other words, three parallel jobs write to three designated files.

Comment: Are you just looking for `{#}`?

Comment: @meuh yes, just the number of enough. `{#}` is perfect if the first `{}` reads the pipeline from the `script`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for {%} which is not the job number, but the job *slot* number.

```
LC_ALL=C seq 10 -0.1 1 | shuf |
  parallel --lb 'echo Job {} grabs {%}; sleep {}; echo Job {} releases {%}'
```

Notice how when a number is released it is grabbed by the next job. So no 2 jobs running in parallel will have the same {%} value.

This is covered in chapter 5 of GNU Parallel 2018 (http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html or https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014).

Comment: I was trying to use this option with the numbering starting at 0. Is there an option to do this? (Background: I wanted to use the job id as variable for setting cuda visible devices).

Comment: @KamSen `parallel --rpl '{%0} 1 $_=$job->slot()-1' echo {%0} ::: a b c` or `parallel 'echo {=1 $_=$job->slot()-1=}' ::: a b c`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the solution is `--link` flag to aggregate the combinations.

```
parallel -u --jobs 3 --link ./script2 {1} {2} :::: <(./script1) ::: {1..3}
```

Then, `{1}` comes from the script, and `{2}` just matches periodically.